# PHP Looping Data

Tags: php

I want to make the first row 'update' button link to A page and second row 'update' button link to B page, but when the PHP function loops it keep showing that both row 'update' button link to the same page.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("smart_train",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM detail");
>
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Station Place</th>
             <th>Line1</th>
             <th>Line2</th>
             <th>Line3</th>
             <th>Station Code</th>
             <th>Opening Hours</th>
             <th>Parking</th>
             <th>Content Control</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
```

```
<?php
                        $i=0;
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        if($i%2==0)
                        $classname="evenRow";
                        else
                        $classname="oddRow";
                   ?>
                  <tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>">   
                    <td> <?php echo $row["place"]; ?> </td>
                    <td id="station_line1"> <?php echo $row["line1"]; ?> </td>
                    <td id="station_line2"> <?php echo $row["line2"]; ?> </td>
                    <td id="station_line3"> <?php echo $row["line3"]; ?> </td>
                    <td id="station_code"> <?php echo $row["code"]; ?> </td>
                    <td id="station_opening"> <?php echo $row["opening"]; ?> </td>
                    <td id="station_parking"> <?php echo $row["parking"]; ?> </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <a href="station_detail _update1.php">
                          <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                          </a>
                          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="content_control_or">or</button></a>
                          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></a>
                          <?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                   <?php
                    $i++;
                    }
                   ?>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: does my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass variable in anchor of that button to redirect on page where page name will be dependent of `$i`'s value.

```
if($i%2==0){
{ 
   $classname="evenRow";
   $goesToPage='Page1.php';
 }
else{
   $classname="oddRow";
   $goesToPage='Page2.php';
}

     <a href="<?php echo $goToPage; ?>">
```

Comment: It prompt out:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\website_testing\AdminLTE-2.3.0\AdminLTE-2.3.0\pages\tables\station_detail.php on line 
[ <tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>"> ]

Comment: can you paste start to end what actually error says?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\website_testing\AdminLTE-2.3.0\AdminLTE-2.3.0\pages\tables\station_detail.php on line 439

Comment: you have used unused '<' find and remove it ans then test it

Comment: line 439: <tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>"> 
But I found no unused '<', the code is on the top

Comment: see you connection code where you have not properly clsed php tag... you have used > instead of ?>

Comment: you can vote up or can accept answer if it helped you to get solution